# Remap Shift + Ctrl to Shift + Alt with AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way for AutoHotKey to re-map the functionality <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> arrow (which highlights everything to the left/right) to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>?

Coming from a Mac I'm so used to having the CMD button next to the space bar and I prefer it that way..

Comment: As a long-time Windows user, I would _strongly_ recommend _not_ doing this; there are many programs that use chorded metakeys (combinations of Ctrl, Alt, and Shift) for program commands, and remapping may well block access to those commands. It would be better to recognize that Windows is _not_ the Mac, and learn to accommodate the differences, just as many Windows users do on the occasions that they have to use Macs or Linux.

Comment: Mhmm.. perhaps, that just sucks though. Long time mac user @ home and forced to use Windows for work

Comment: No different than those of us who use Windows at home, and have to use Linux or Macs at work...

Comment: Irrelevant for this question though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; "LShift + LAlt + Left" to "Shift + Ctrl  + Left"
<+<!Left:: Send {Ctrl Down}{Shift Down}{Left}{Shift Up}{Ctrl Up}

; "LShift + LAlt + Right" to "Shift + Ctrl  + Right"
<+<!Right:: Send {Ctrl Down}{Shift Down}{Right}{Shift Up}{Ctrl Up}
```

- "<+" is the modifier symbol for the LShift and "<"!" for the LAlt key.
- Modifier symbols are used only in key combinations for modifying
  other keys (in this case the keys left and right arrow).
- All other LShift + LAlt + Key combinations in the system or programs  (if any)  remain intact.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Comment: `<+<!+` didn't work for me, however explicitly setting `LShift & LAlt & Left` instead did.

Comment: @HeyJude, **`<+<!+`** means **"LShift + LAlt + plus(+)"** The symbols <+ for LShift and <! for LAlt are only used in key combinations to modify other keys (the keys Left and Right in this answer.